# EntityFramework Code First Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I have the follow context, mapping and class that uses for work with oracle:

```
public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public string Schema { get; set; }

        public Context(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<User> UserDbSet { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMapping(Schema));
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public decimal Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
    {
        public UserMapping(string schema = "dbo")
        {
            HasKey(t => t.Id);
            ToTable(schema + ".TBLUSER");

            Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
            Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("NAME");
            Property(t => t.LastName).HasColumnName("LASTNAME");
        }
    }
```

But when i call the:

```
var context = new Context("name=ORACLE")
            {
                Schema = "USERTABLESPACEDEFAULT"
            };

        var users = context.UserDbSet.ToList();
```

The oracle Privider shows me the follow error:

**{"ORA-00904: \"Extent1\".\"Id\": invalid identifier"}**

And thats is why EntityFrameworks try to execute the follow query:

```
SELECT 
"Extent1"."Id" AS "Id", 
"Extent1"."NAME" AS "NAME", 
"Extent1"."LASTNAME" AS "LASTNAME"
FROM "USERTABLESPACEDEFAULT"."TBLUSER" "Extent1"
```

Any .dll its necesary ??

Here is my connectionString:

```
<add name="ORACLE" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=localhost:1521/XE;PASSWORD=Isolucion2015*;USER ID=SYSTEM" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
```

Comment: So, what is the column name?  Is it really `Id`?  Or is it `ID`?  Because once the column names are wrapped in double quotes, the name is case sensitive, so you have to get the casing right.

Comment: @sstan Yes, the problem was in oracle is ID and I was mapping Id. There is a way to Oracle works the same name columns than sql server ??

Comment: This is quite unrelated, but you may want to remove your password in your connection string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was recently faced with the same problem of upper case names and Oracle so there is now Nuget package to take care of that.

Including [EntityFramework.OracleHelpers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.OracleHelpers) and doing oneliner will apply uppercase table, column and foreign key conventions.

```
  using EntityFramework.OracleHelpers;

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
        this.ApplyAllConventionsIfOracle(modelBuilder);
  }
```

More info and examples are at [GitHub page](https://github.com/b0/EntityFramework.OracleHelpers).

Answer (score 5):

Ty changing this line:

```
Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
```

...to this:

```
Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("ID"); // Upper case ID.
```

By default, Oracle's column names are in upper case.  And when EF generates the names wrapped in double quotes, you have to make sure you get the casing right.

If you really want to keep using `"Id"`, then you either have to find a way to have EF not place the double quotes around `Id` so that the name check is not case sensitive (I don't know how to do that).

Or, you have to rename the column in Oracle to be exactly `Id`.

```
alter table tbluser rename column id to "Id";
```

But really, I think you should just change your string to `"ID"` and be done with it.

Comment: Ok, and I suppose that at the moment of create is the same "rule"

Comment: You mean when you create the table?  Yes, if you really want to force a certain casing of a table name or column name, then you need to surround it with double quotes.

Comment: Ok, thanks .. Another question a little diferent, have you a script where you create a tablespace with user login and grant privilegies to user tablespace ...

Comment: Sorry, that's out of scope for this site.