# Entity Framework many to many complex query unable to create error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I have a relational database and I want to get a relational query but could not.

- I have many to many relation UserGroup and WidgetContent.
- One to many relation between Widget and WidgetContent.
- Many to many relation between User and UserGroup.

Code:

```
public class UserGroup
{
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<WidgetContent> WidgetContents { get; set; }
}

public class WidgetContent
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Widget Widget { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
}

public class Widget
{
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<WidgetContent> WidgetContents { get; set; }
}
```

So I want to send a `WidgetId` parameter to my web api action and get user group of authenticated user.

And get the related widget contents of related user group of authenticated user.

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Widget(Guid? widgetId)
    {
        var username = User.GetUsername();
        var groups = context.UserGroups.Where(s => s.Users.Any(p => p.Username == username)).ToList();

        IOrderedQueryable<WidgetContent> data = context.WidgetContents
                      .Include(s => s.Widget)
                      .Where(s => s.WidgetId == widgetId && s.UserGroups.Intersect(groups).Any())
                      .OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedAt);
    }
```

But this query returns an error like this:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'MyContext.Users.UserGroup'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `Intersect` that is causing the exception. To avoid it you could do this:

```
var groups = context.UserGroups.Where(s => s.Users.Any(p => p.Username == username))
                               .Select(e=>e.Id);
IOrderedQueryable<WidgetContent> data = context.WidgetContents
              .Include(s => s.Widget)
              .Where(s => s.WidgetId == widgetId 
                       && s.UserGroups.Any(e=>groups.Contains(e.Id)))
              .OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedAt);
```

Unfortunately you can't use `Intersect` with entity types. As the exception is pointing out you need to work with primitive types or enumeration types. In this kind of scenario I always use the combination of `Any` and `Contains` extension methods as I showed above.

### Update

If I understand well you want to apply the first condition first, bring the result to memory and apply the second condition using Linq to Objects. If that is what you want to try then you could do this:

```
var groups = context.UserGroups.Where(s => s.Users.Any(p => p.Username == username))
                               .Select(e=>e.Id);
var data = context.WidgetContents
                  .Include(s => s.Widget)
                  .Where(s => s.WidgetId == widgetId).ToList();
var result= data.Where(s=>s.UserGroups.Any(e=>groups.Contains(e.Id))
                .OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedAt);
```

Comment: This thime returns 500 internal error but does not gives any error message now. I set try catch block but did not stop in catch. May be any problem Guid id selection?

Comment: Yes, doing the selection you are using a type that EF knows how to manage at the time to do comparisons, eg, in the code `Any` is going to be converted to an `Exist` and `Contains` into an `IN`

Comment: I find error code returned by oracle `ora-00904 extent1 . id invalid identifier`

Comment: Is too generic. Maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31389461/entityframework-code-first-oracle) helps. Sorry I'm not an expert working with Oracle. Install this [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.OracleHelpers) and add what the solution said in the `OnModelCreating` method

Comment: I think is because PK in Oracle needs to be upper case:`Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("ID"); // Upper case ID`

Comment: My oracle table column name is "Id" not "ID"

Comment: In the [post I quoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31389461/entityframework-code-first-oracle) there are at least two solutions , did you try with some of them?

Comment: Can we split where clause? Before select all widgets . `Where(s => s.WidgetId == widgetId)` and then select group id matched in this colelction.

Comment: Can I get all `Where(s => s.WidgetId == widgetId)` in memory and then select by group?

Comment: You can do it, but that doesn't save you from that exception, I think that is problem with your EF model

Comment: Why? Queries will be executed. All groups and Widget contents come from database and match them in memory.